# I moved my /var/cache folder and broke the permissions. How can I restore them/find what they are supposed to be?

Tags: apt, permissions, filesystem

I recently reinstalled Ubuntu 20.04 and made my /var partition a little too small. To avoid having to reinstall, I thought I would just move the large /var/cache folder to another drive and symlink it, but I appear to have broken ownership and/or permissions.

I've tried recursively changing ownership to _apt for the /var/cache/apt folder, and similar for man for /var/cache/man, but when installing with apt, it's still not working properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than symlink, mounting a partition to `/var/cache` would likely accomplish your goals. As for file permissions, it's best not to guess with these things. This is what I have in my `/var/cache` directory (yours may differ):

```
drwxr-xr-x 19 root root  4096  5月 10  2020 ./
drwxr-xr-x 15 root root  4096  2月  4  2020 ../
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096  4月 17  2019 PackageKit/
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096  2月  4  2020 apache2/
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root  4096 10月 24  2019 app-info/
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096  7月  2  2019 apparmor/
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096  1月 27 09:46 apt/
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096  4月 17  2019 cracklib/
drwxrwx---  3 root lp    4096  1月 27 00:00 cups/
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096  1月 20 06:45 debconf/
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096  4月 17  2019 dictionaries-common/
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 24576  1月 26 17:01 fontconfig/
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096  1月 27 06:12 fwupd/
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    16  5月 10  2020 fwupdmgr -> private/fwupdmgr
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096  3月 16  2019 gdm/
drwx------  2 root root  4096  1月 13 21:59 ldconfig/
drwxr-xr-x 36 man  man   4096  1月 27 00:00 man/
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   160  9月  7 08:00 motd-news
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096  2月  4  2020 postgresql/
drwx------  3 root root  4096  5月 10  2020 private/
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096  1月 26 17:41 snapd/
```

However, even with this listing you cannot blindly set permissions. Case in point would be `/var/cache/cups`, which is used for printing, where different files have different permissions:

```
drwxrwx---  3 root lp      4096  1月 27 00:00 ./
drwxr-xr-x 19 root root    4096  5月 10  2020 ../
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    2534  1月 27 00:00 Canon_TS8230.data
-rw-r--r--  1 root root     280  1月 27 00:00 Canon_TS8230.strings
-rw-r--r--  1 root root     387  1月 15  2020 cups-browsed-options-canon_ts8230
-rw-r--r--  1 root root     406  1月 27 00:00 cups-browsed-options-Canon_TS8230
-rw-r-----  1 root lp        64  1月 27 00:00 job.cache
-rw-r-----  1 root lp        64  1月 26 00:00 job.cache.O
-rw-r--r--  1 root root       7  1月 27 00:00 org.cups.cupsd
-rw-------  1 lp   lp   6818188  5月  9  2020 ppds.dat
-rw-r--r--  1 root root     308  5月  9  2020 ppd-updates
drwxrwxr-x  2 root lp      4096  2月 16  2019 rss/
```

As you've recently re-installed the OS, you likely already have a lot of your important files backed up safely. Wipe the machine, re-install, carry on. If you really must put core tables on different partitions/storage devices in the future, use mount points to save the headache

Comment: Yeah, turns out /var was too small, so I thought this might work, oh well. I was trying to set up so I could make root read-only, but I keep forgetting that trying new things like that probably shouldn't be done on the 'production' machine.